# how to turn off ANSI escape color codes in rails 4 logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, logging

In my rails 4 logs I get a log of garbage like this:

```
^{[1m^{[36mPerson Load (0.7ms)^{[0m  ^{[1mSELECT  "people".* FROM "people" 
  WHERE "people"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1^{[0m  [["id", 673143]]
```

How can I tell rails 4 to turn this coloring off ?

I tried to add `config.active_record.colorize_logging = false` to `config/application.rb` but I got this error:

> `` /home/sweerasinghe/trunk_1509171953/vendors/ruby-2.2.2/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `colorize_logging=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError) ``

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You want this:

```
config.colorize_logging = false
```

This is documented in the [Rails General Configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration) section of the Configurating Rails Applications Rails Guide.

Comment: While this answer may be correct, please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Comment: The only underlying logic is that `config.active_record.colorize_logging` is not a configuration option that exists, and `config.colorize_logging` is. I've edited my answer to include a link to documentation.

Comment: It's `config.colorize_logging` for Rails > 3.x, and it used to be `config.active_record.colorize_logging ` for Rails <= 2.x.